# Pandas dataframe displayed without borders in iPython

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, anaconda

My dataframes used to display like this:

[image]

Then, one day, I realized the borders were not showing anymore:

[image]

I don't know what happened.

I have Python 3.4 which I installed using the Anaconda bundle which comes shipped with Python, pandas, iPython, and Spyder. So, I am accessing iPython through the Spyder environment.

After the problem with the border happened, I uninstalled Anaconda, and installed it again, but I got the same issue.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This functionality was removed in IPython 3.0.

This was [reported](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/G61rU_nKN_Y/ycHLS3vW9QUJ) to the Anaconda Google groups page in May 2015.

> I think you're [were] using an old version of Spyder (2.3.0, 2.3.1 or 2.3.2)
>   on Windows because support for printing DataFrames as html tables was
>   removed in recent versions (i.e. since [Spyder] 2.3.3).
>
> I'm sorry we've had to remove it, but it was causing other problems
>   and (more importantly) it stopped to be supported by IPython 3.0+.

Then more explicitly in a [later](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/G61rU_nKN_Y/S6aUWhGv6IUJ) post:

> There is *no* way to get the functionality mentioned by the OP again because it was removed by IPython in its 3.0 version.